SonarQube Cognitive Complexity and Local Functions
I started using Local Functions instead of private methods when these private methods were used only by a single call point. The thing is that now, SonarQube is complaining about Cognitive Complexity because it adds the actual method AND all the local functions complexity.
Since the main goal of splitting the function in multiple subs was precisely to reduce the complexity, how can I tell SonarQube it is okay without having to add warning suppressions everywhere?

If that's ok with you, you can ignore this type of warnings in SQ

in all fairness, you DID increase the cognitive complexity.

Static local functions are now excluded from the cognitive complexity calculation - see the discussion here. Non-static local functions are still considered to contribute to the cognitive complexity, however.

@IvanPetrov How is this adding more cognitive complexity than a private method? The only thing that changes is scope.

@MatthewWatson this makes a lot of sense, since no capturing is going on.

@bkqc not really, non-static local functions capture state of the enclosing function. They have to be defined after the state that they use etc...that all adds cognitive load. Not so with static, see Matthew Watson's comment.
